# Disable spring security for POST method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a spring security configuration like follows.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/imgs/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
    .fullyAuthenticated().and()
    //.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/updatepass/**").permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .failureUrl("/login?error=401").permitAll().and()
    //.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/updatepass").and()
    .logout().permitAll().and().csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/registeruser").hasRole("ADMIN");
```

I want to allow `/updatepass` POST method allowed for any request even if it's not a autherized request. I tried the following commented configurations, but still it's throwing me login page.

My target POST URL to be opened for is an API which would recieve a JSON request. and the complete URL is `/updatepass` I tried adding `/**` nothing works. Please don't suggest XML Configuration. Only Java configuration please.

Comment: You can use something like this: <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/client/edit" access="isAuthenticated" method="GET" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/client/edit" access="hasRole('EDITOR')" method="POST" />
</http>

Comment: Thanks @FadySaad but I don't want to use xml. Complete Java config.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding the overloaded method of `configure(WebSecurity web)` with following implementation.

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
               throws Exception {
     web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/updatepass/**");
}
```